# how to write servlet that sends email to gmail without getting flagged

Tags: java, email, authentication, servlets

We are writing an application that needs to allow users to register.  The typical method is that the user types in registration information including their email address.  The system then sends them an email.  When they reply, the registration is confirmed.

The code is in Java servlets.  Here's the relevant method:

```
public void sendEmail(HttpServletRequest request){
        //your host
        String host = "nexus.stevens.edu";

        //email from
        String from = "user@stevens.edu";

        //email to
        String to = request.getParameter("email-address");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        // Get the default Session object.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try{
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("Registeration Confirm");

        // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
        message.setContent("<h1>Congradulations to register successfully!</h1></br>" +
                "<p>Your username is:  "+userName+"</p>"+
                "<p>Your password is:  "+password+"</p>"+"PleaseRemeber!",
                "text/html" );

        // Send message
        Transport transport=session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("nexus.stevens.edu","user","password"); 
        transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
```

The user writing this code can send to himself on gmail with the spam filter turned all the way down.  For any of the rest of us, it bounces.  But he can log into his email and send an email, which of course gets through.  How do we authenticate to our server?

Comment: Read about SPF and DKIM.

Comment: How exactly do you send an email?